# PictureBox- Grids and Filling in squares (Game of Life)

Tags: c#

I am learning C# through implementing a copy of the Game of Life. I have been able to successfully draw a grid over the `pictureBox` using for loops. The bool named `fill_in` is To fill in squares. I am requesting help in making the squares clickable. I have set the propertite attribute of `pictureBox` to allow `pictureBox_MouseClick`. In side the mouseClick event I have set the coordinates `x` and `y`. The problem is that the if statement inside that event is incorrect since `==` cannot be applied to bool operands.

How can I do an if condition statement that will fill with black color if the bool `fill_in` is true?

**Code**

```
  namespace life
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            Graphics paper;
            bool[,] fill_in = new bool[450, 450];

        public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

            }


    //makes grid in picture box
    private void drawGrid()
            {
                int numOfCells = 100;
                int cellSize = 10;
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
                paper.Clear(Color.White);

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++)
                {   
                    // Vertical
                    paper.DrawLine(p, i * cellSize, 0, i * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
                    // Horizontal
                    paper.DrawLine(p, 0, i * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, i * cellSize);
                }
            }


    // populate bool fill_in with true (alive) or false (dead)
            private void clearGrid()
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 450; x = x + 10)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 450; y = y + 10)
                    {
                        fill_in[x, y] = false;
                    }
                }
            }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                drawGrid();
                clearGrid();

                for (int x = 0; x < 440; x = x + 10)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 440; y = y + 10)
                    {
                        if (fill_in[x, y] == true)
                            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
                    }
                }
            }

     private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {

                int x = e.X;
                int y = e.Y;
                int i = x / 10;
                int j = y / 10;


                fill_in[i, j] = !fill_in[i, j];

                if (fill_in[i, j])
                {

                 paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
                }
                else
                {

                paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, x, y, 10, 10);       

                }

                }

                }
           }
```

After Changes to the if statement:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if (fill_in == true)` in `pictureBox1_MouseClick` is missing the array subscripts (`fill_in` is an array, remember?).

But it doesn't matter; you already know `fill_in[i, j]` is true, because you just made it that way, so you can remove the `if` entirely.

If you're looking to fill it in on the first click, and un-fill it (restore it to "unfilled"), you can just change your event handler a little:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int x = e.X;
  int y = e.Y;
  int i = x / 10;
  int j = y / 10;

  // Reverse the value of fill_in[i, j] - if it was false, change to true,
  // and if true change to false
  fill_in[i, j] = !fill_in[i, j];

  if (fill_in[i, j])
  {
    // Fill grid square with the filled color
  }
  else
  {
    // Fill grid square with unfilled color            
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is almost perfect. The only problem is that the fill in squares are not matching the grid squares. Take a look at the picture above.

Comment: No wonder it's not matching, since you're drawing the square at the position of the mouse click, right? You need to align it to the nearest cell in the grid. So you might want to do something like int x = cellSize * (e.X / cellSize);

Comment: Your question asked about something else (the `if` statement not working), not how to do the drawing. If you have a question about properly drawing the grid now, it should be a separate question. You can provide a link to this one to provide background. (It's not really proper to change the main point of your question after people start posting answers to it - it's pretty hard to hit a moving target.)